# How to get an array of unique properties from an array of complex objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects similar to

```
const array = [
{
    documentId: "document1",
    writers: [
        {
            name: "writer1", 
            date: "2017-12-11"
        },
        {
            name: "writer2", 
            date: "2017-12-11"
        }
    ]
},
{
    documentId: "document2",
    writers: [
        {
            name: "writer1", 
            date: "2017-12-11"
        },
        {
            name: "writer3", 
            date: "2017-12-11"
        }
    ]
},
{
    documentId: "document3",
    writers: [
        {
            name: "writer3", 
            date: "2017-12-11"
        },
        {
            name: "writer4", 
            date: "2017-12-11"
        }
    ]
},
```

I'm trying to extract all the unique writer's names and match them to all the documents they have written so that the final array looks something like this:

```
const finalArray = [
    {name: "writter1", documents: ["document1", "document2"]},
    {name: "writter2", documents: ["document1"]},
    {name: "writter3", documents: ["document2", "document3"]},
    {name: "writter4", documents: ["document3"]}
]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. That would really help us to figure out the issue with your code. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Map` to keep writers as keys then call `reduce` on your array to map documents to writers, then call `values()` on the `Map` object:

```
const ret = Array.from(array.reduce((acc, val) => {
  val.writers.forEach(({ name }) => {
    let w = acc.get(name) || { name: name, documents: [] };
    w.documents = w.documents.concat(val.documentId);
    acc.set(name, w);
  });
  return acc;
}, new Map()).values());

console.log(ret);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) which takes all names and the associated documents. If no map is avaliable for a name, then create a new entry.

A then end, get all objects of the map.

```js
var array = [{ documentId: "document1", writers: [{ name: "writer1", date: "2017-12-11" }, { name: "writer2", date: "2017-12-11" }] }, { documentId: "document2", writers: [{ name: "writer1", date: "2017-12-11" }, { name: "writer3", date: "2017-12-11" }] }, { documentId: "document3", writers: [{ name: "writer3", date: "2017-12-11" }, { name: "writer4", date: "2017-12-11" }] }],
    map = new Map,
    result;

array.forEach(function (o) {
    o.writers.forEach(function ({ name }) {
        map.has(name) || map.set(name, { name, documents: [] });
        map.get(name).documents.push(o.documentId);
    });
});

result = Array.from(map.values());

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there will be a more elegant map-reduce solution. Anyway, this will works even if it's ugly:

```
const array = //your data
var output = []
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    for (let k = 0; k < array[i].writers.length; k++) {
        let t = output.find(function(a){return array[i].writers[k].name === a.name})
        if (t)
            t.documents.push(array[i].documentId)
        else
            output.push({name: array[i].writers[k].name, documents: [array[i].documentId]})
  }
console.log(output)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/50oph5g4/1/